# Rails NoMethodError in versioning controller path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to refresh my knowledge with building Rails monolit app after 2 years working with Rails::API only. I used Rails scaffold to build `Property` (`rails generate scaffold property`) which at the end gives me model, controller and views. Now I'm trying to use versioning in to have controller structure: `api/v1/properties_controller`. For this example let's assume I want to have only `Index` action, routes as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :properties, only: [:index]
    end
  end
end
```

and rake routes shows me expected results:

```
                           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                api_v1_properties GET    /api/v1/properties(.:format)                                                             api/v1/properties#index
```

But when I was trying to reach out the path I'm getting an error:

```
Api::V1::PropertiesController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html
```

Which means I don't have views inside `views/api/v1/property`. When I moved all scaffolded views from `app/views/properties` to `app/views/api/v1/properties` I'm getting an error:

```
NoMethodError in Api::V1::Properties#index
undefined method `property_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fc4b6656f08>:0x00007fc4b66540a0>
Extracted source (around line #23):
(...)
23        <td><%= link_to 'Show', property %></td>
```

Is there any quick way to transfer these paths in to correct one or should I missed something?

`index.html.erb`

```
  <tbody>
    <% @properties.each do |property| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= property.name %></td>
        <td><%= property.status %></td>
        <td><%= property.name_tag %></td>
        <td><%= property.portfolio_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', property %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_property_path(property) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', property, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

There have `Show`, `Edit`, `Destroy` links in `index.html.erb`. So you need define them in `routes.rb`:

```rb
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :properties, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :delete]
  end
end
```

Add you need to add namespace `api_vi` to paths in `index.html.erb`:

```rb
<td><%= link_to 'Show', api_v1_property_path(property) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', api_v1_edit_property_path(property) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', api_v1_property_path(property), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Comment: Ok but how to pair with the views inside of path `app/views/properties` instead of `app/views/api/v1/properties` ? I think path `api/v1/...` is not a good practice.